# Python Pandas Resample Time Series Function

Tags: python, function, pandas, datetime, time-series

I want my function to resample the pandas Series that is passed into the various frequencies - samples, I feel like I am almost there except it seems to be keeping the old index instead of creating a resampled index and produces a lot of NaN values:

```
index=pd.date_range('2015-10-1 00:00:00', '2018-12-31 23:50:00', freq='30min')
df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(index),2).cumsum(axis=0),columns=['A','B'],index=index)


def resample(ts):
    samples = ['60m','4h','D','1h','W']
    counter = 0
    resampled = {}
    while counter < len(samples):
        for i in samples:
            ts = ts.resample(i).mean()
            resampled[i]=ts
            counter+=1
    return resampled


data = resample(df.A)

data['W']

2015-11-01     21.396793
2015-11-08           NaN
2015-11-15           NaN
2015-11-22           NaN
```

So basically I want 5 new arrays of re sampled time series.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give an example output?

Comment: `'60m'` should be `'1h'` unless you're going for 60 months.

Comment: it's there: data['W']

Comment: That `while` loop is unnecessary.

Comment: In my opinion you want upsample your data, so instead `ts = ts.resample(i).mean()` need `ts = ts.resample(i).ffill()` or somrthing similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
index=pd.date_range('2015-10-1 00:00:00', '2018-12-31 23:50:00', freq='30min')
df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(index),2).cumsum(axis=0),columns=['A','B'],index=index)
```

The rest of your code is largely extraneous:

```
data = {freq: df['A'].resample(freq).mean() for freq in ['60m','4h','D','1h','W']}
```

`data` now has 5 elements in it where each is a resampled DataFrame.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need upsample your data, so need change `mean` to `ffill` or `bfill` functions, also need `60T` for `60 minutes`:

```
def resample(ts):
    samples = ['60T','4h','D','1h','W']
    resampled = {}
    for i in samples:
        ts = ts.resample(i).ffill()
        resampled[i]=ts
    return resampled
```